# Size Range of ext4 Filesystem Journal

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4, suse

The *minimum* and *maximum* sizes respectively for the **ext3** filesystem journal are 1,024 blocks and 102,400 blocks. Similarly — what are the *minimum* and *maximum* sizes for the journal on an **ext4** filesystem?

Comment: The same; ext4 *is* ext3, plus a few additional options enabled.

Comment: @psusi The _maximum_ size of the journal on ext3 is *102,400* blocks, which means that a filesystem with 4KiB blocks can have a journal at most 400MiB in size. 
   
However, this [article](http://www.linux-mag.com/id/7666/) on Linux-Mag describes an ext4 filesystem with a 1GiB journal, which would be *524,288* blocks, so it seems to me that ext4 must have a higher limit than ext3 for the size of its journal.

Comment: It seems the limit was increased to 10,240,000 blocks for both ext3 and ext4, though the man page for `tune2fs` hasn't been updated ( the man page for `mke2fs` has ).